# how can i add a .jpg file in local report(.rdlc) in c# withour storing the pics in database

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

how can i add a .jpg file in local report in c# withour storing the pics in database

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to get an image on a Microsoft Reporting Document.

Database
Embedded
External

I guess you know how do database by your question.
Chalkey gives a great example of how to do an embedded image. (This is the approach I generally take.)
Finally there are external images. For external you can set the property on the image to external and either refernece a file path or even a url in the value property.
Lastly you have set the external image property too in code:

i.e. reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

When you are designing your report in Visual Studio click on *Report* from the menu bar and then *Embedded images*. Select the image you want and click ok. Next from the toolbar add a new image onto the report. Goto the properties of that image and select *Source* as *Embedded*. The *Value* property will now contain the image you just embedded into the report.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a 100% sure what you mean by "local report in C#" but I would hazard a guess and suggest you add the picture file to the image resources of your project.